# $\sum a_n$ be convergent but not absolutely convergent, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum a_n$ be convergent but not absolutely convergent, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=0$,$s_k$ denotes the partial sum then could anyone tell me which of the following is/are correct?

$1.$ $s_k=0$ for infinitely many $k$

$2$. $s_k>0$ and $<0$ for infnitely many $k$

3.$s_k>0$ for all $k$

4.$s_k>0$ for all but finitely many $k$

if we take $a_n=(-1)^n{1\over n}$ then $\sum a_n$ is convergent but not absolutely convergent,but I don't know $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=0$? so I am puzzled could any one tell me how to proceed?

Comment: experiment with $-sum+1-1/2+1/3-1/4+1/5\cdots$ and see which answer is likely.

Comment: For 2) I would say Sk > 0 OR Sk < 0 How can it be greater and less at the same time? I would rule out number 1) since a Conditionally Conv Series can sum up to anything depending on the arrangement. Let's see what others have to say.

Comment: By the way, for $4.$ try to understand what does it exactly mean. And find *any* series for which it is not satisfied

Comment: For (3) and (4), just note that if $a_k$ has this property then $b_k=-a_k$ has the same property.

Comment: I have edited $4$, but I am confused as I am not getting an example for which $\sum a_n=0$

Comment: @miosaki your series converges to $-\ln(2)$

Comment: I think the problem here is: Are we allowed to change the order in which we add them up? We are only given the sum of the series, no formula. Because arrangements is the big thing here. THat's why I am a little confused here. I don't know where you got that question form, but I would not put the question in those words on my quiz...

Comment: the question seems  incomplete. Parts 3 and 4 need to have counterparts with inequality in opposite direction. as in (3) $s_k<0$ for all $k$ or $s_k>0$ for all $k$. (4) $s_k>0$ for infinitely $k$ or $s_k<0$ for infinitely  many $k$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of them are necessarily true.

We can easily compute a series from its partial sums, so let's specify the $s_k$.

Define
$$
s_k=\left\{\begin{array}{}
-\frac1k&\text{if $k$ is odd}\\[4pt]
-\frac1{k^2}&\text{if $k$ is even}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then $a_1=-1$ and for $k\gt1$,
$$
a_k=\left\{\begin{array}{}
\frac1{(k-1)^2}-\frac1k&\text{if $k$ is odd}\\[4pt]
\frac1{k-1}-\frac1{k^2}&\text{if $k$ is even}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Show that this series is not absolutely convergent, its sum is $0$, and it fails to satisfy any of the conditions.

Comment: Sir what if in given question options (3) and (4) are changed as: (3) it is possible that $s_k>0$ for all $k$ and (4) it is possible that $s_k>0$ for all but a finite number of values of $k$. Please help

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to see that the first statement is wrong. The idea for a counterexample is in 3.

For the second statement use Riemann's rearrengement theorem, which (if you unterstood the proof) gives you the existence of such a series.

For the third statement construct $a_k$ such that $s_k=(-1)^k \cdot \frac{1}{k}$.

The fourth look at the third.

On the other hand all of the things can be true.

For the first let $(b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an arbitrary null sequence. Define $a_n$ via
\[a_n= \begin{cases} b_k & 2k=n\\
-b_k & 2k+1=n
\end{cases} \]
We see that 
\[  \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = 0\]
and furthermore 
\[\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1} a_n=0\]
for any $N\in \mathbb{N}$. If you chose a "slow" enough null sequence it won't be absolute convergent.

For the second to be true use the series constructed in the first part at 3.

For the third part make something that a subsequence of $s_k$ is $\frac{1}{k}$, and blow up the rest with $n$ terms with values $\pm \frac{1}{n}$ and let $n \to \infty$ while $k\to \infty$.

The fourth is solved by the third.

Comment: i have already said about $s_k$ u missed

Comment: @miosaki sorry about that. added some stuff to my answer

Comment: only (3) and (4) correct.right?