# partial sum of series which is convergent but not absolutely convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am stuck on the following exercise.

It is given that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent, but not absolutely convergent and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=0$. Denote by $s_k$ the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^k a_n$, k=1,2,...    Then

1. $s_k=0$ for infinitely many k
2. $s_k>0$ for  infinitely many k, and $s_k<0$ for infinitely many k
3. it is possible that $s_k>0$ for all k
4. it is possible that $s_k>0$ for all but a finite number of values of k

Here $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\lim_{k\to \infty}s_k=0$ hence it is possible that its partial sum $s_k=0$ for infinitely many k, hence first option is correct.

Here series is convergent but not absolutely convergent therefore this series has negative terms  hence $s_k$ can be greater than and less than $0$ infinitely many times ,hence option 2 is correct.
I have example $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ this series is convergent but not absolutely convergent and $s_k>0$ for all k for this series, hence option 3 is correct.
I am not getting option 4.

please correct me if i am wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that all four options happen all the time? that each of the four options can happen some of the time? that one of the options must happen all of the time? Please clarify.

Comment: i am trying to prove that each of the four  options can happen some of the time. sorry for late response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\sum a_n$ be convergent but not absolutely convergent, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400335/sum-a-n-be-convergent-but-not-absolutely-convergent-sum-n-1-infty-a-n)

Answer (score 1):

I am gonna assume you want sequences which satisfy the given conditions individually. Because some of them are contradictory to each other. So you can't find a single sequence satisfying all conditions. One more thing, the sequence you considered for option $3$, won't work out since it doesn't converge to $0$, which is one of the requirement.

Consider $ \{1,\,-1,\,1/2,\,-1/2,\, 1/3,\,-1/3...\}$ the sum converges to $0$, and doesn't converge absolutely, and the sum is $0$ for Infinitely $k$, for even numbered groups.

Say if you were to swap every other pair, then the sequence would be    $ \{1,\,-1,\,1/2,\,-1/2,\, -1/3,\,1/3, \,-1/4, \,1/4...\}$, then for some infinite $k$, sum is negative for other infinite $k$ it is positive. So option $1,\, 2$ are possible.

Take $ \{-log\, 2, \, 1\, , -1/2\, , 1/3\, ,-1/4\}$, sum will be positive for all $k$, except for first one. The sum still goes to zero, not absolutely convergent. So option $4$ is possible. It should easy to find out why option 3 is not possible taking the same example, and modifying it little bit.

Comment: You are saying option 3 is not possible?

Comment: Yes. I came up with counterexamples for other options

Comment: Why can't the partial sums be $1,1/10,1/2,1/100,1/3,1/1000,1/4,1/10000,\dots$?

Comment: For which option?

Comment: Option 3, the one you say is not possible.

Comment: The sum is not zero

Comment: what is sum of series {(-1)^n+1} / n and how?

Comment: how to find sum of series {(-1)^n+1 / n}?  finding sum of series is difficult task for me ,give me some hint how to find sum of series.

Comment: I listed the partial sums, jnyan, and they clearly have limit zero. The terms of the sequence are $1,1/10-1,1/2-1/10,1/100-1/2,1/3-1/100,\dots$.

Comment: @dipali, try Taylor series of log x.

Comment: @gerry, Check for its absolute convergence.

Comment: I am sorry. The third option is also possible

Answer (score 0):

1. Take $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Then $s_1=-1,s_2=\frac{-1}{2}$,...

We have $s_n<0$ for all $n$. So A is false .

2. B is false also

3.Take $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$.

Then $s_n>0$ for all $n$.

Comment: The examples are supposed to satisfy $\sum a_n=0$.