# Examples of convergent (but not absolutely convergent) series under given conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be a convergent (but not absolutely convergent) series with $S=0$. Let $S_k=\sum_{n=1}^ka_n$ be the partial sum ($k\geq 1$).

What are examples of:

- $S_k=0$ for infinitely many $k$
- $S_k>0$ for infinitely many $k$ and $S_k<0$ for infinitely many $k$
- $S_k>0$ for all $k$
- $S_k>0$ for all but a finite number of $k$

I am not able to think of an example for the given situations. Please help me, I am a beginner.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also what is a valve?

Comment: @BillO'Haran probably a typo for value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\sum a_n$ be convergent but not absolutely convergent, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400335/sum-a-n-be-convergent-but-not-absolutely-convergent-sum-n-1-infty-a-n)

Answer (score 1):

All sequences start at index $1$ as given in the question.

For (i), use $a_{2p} = \frac{-1}{p}$ and $a_{2p-1} = \frac{1}{p}$.

For (ii), with $b_n= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$, it is clear that the series alternates (using [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) ).

Take $(c_k)_{k\geq 0}$ so that $c_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, again using telescoping series, you have an example for (iii) and (iv) (for (iv), just offset the sequence with zeroes at the begininng).